# Jenkins sfdx jwt login issue

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, jwt, jenkins

So we're using Jenkins to integrate between our Salesforce environments and having an issue with one job in particular. The job copies the code base from our production environment and sends the updates to our Bit Bucket master repository. Before we get dinged about that, we are moving toward Bit Bucket being the code base source of truth and it's a complicated mess at the moment.

The issue is this: the User who managed the system has been let go and the job which uses SFDX (the only one that does) is no longer working and we thought we knew why.

We have updated the server certificate, updated OpenSSL, updated SFDX CLI, and updated all the plugins and Jenkins versions.

We are able to authorize using Powershell on the virtual server itself so we know that communication between the server and Salesforce works properly. The job, when run, errors out with the following error:

Salesforce Master Repo Refresh] $ [shell file stuff] sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --username !{SF_USER} -f !{KEY_FILE} -i !{SERVER_CERT} -r !{URL} -s
ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Hereâ€™s the error: error:25078067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library

So, with OpenSSL updated and permissions on the server set to full access, we have no idea what this issue is or how to fix it. Everything we have researched has said OpenSSL is the issue, but that isn't the case.

Any information or ideas would be greatly appreciated.